# class design for wrapper around unmanaged code

Tags: c#, .net

Am writing a wrapper in c# around unmanaged code. The unmanaged code creates a session and session can be either dynamic or static based upon two method calls.

dynamic and static contains different types hence I cannot use an interface here.

If CreateDynamic is called then it's dynamic
else it's static.

My initial class design looks like this.

```
public class Session
{
    public void CreateDynamic()
    {
        dynamic = new Dynamic();
    }

    public void CreateStatic()
    {
        stat = new Static();
    }

    public Dynamic dynamic;
    public Static stat;
}
```

Once I create a session, the object should contain methods and properties that are applicable to the session created. Accessing the uninstantiated sub session will result in null reference exception. Is there any way to get around this problem?

Comment: Make those fields *private* for starters.  Think *abstract base class* next.

Comment: @HansPassant-Can you explain in detail?

Answer (score 0):

You could create two different session classes and use a static class to create the appropriate session. For example:

```
interface ISession
{
    // Common methods
}

interface IDynamicSession : ISession
{
    // Methods unique to a dynamic session
}

interface IStaticSession : ISession
{
    // Methods unique to a static session
}

public class DynamicSession : IDynamicSession
{
}

public class StaticSession : IStaticSession
{
}

public static class Session
{
    public IDynamicSession CreateDynamic()
    {
        return new DynamicSession();
    }

    public IStaticSession CreateStatic()
    {
        return new StaticSession();
    }
}
```